# cloudrail-sdk-java: Twitter

Tags: java, twitter, cloudrail

currently, I try to use CloudRail with the last version of *cloudrail-si-java* (version: 2.21.1), but I get this error with Twitter API:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ServiceCode
>   Error in function authenticate at 13  at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:111)    at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.callFunction(Interpreter.java:45)
>     at com.cloudrail.si.services.Twitter.login(Twitter.java:909)    at
>   com.whois.multiPlateformPosting.testDemo.main(testDemo.java:27)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   java.io.Reader.(Reader.java:78)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.(InputStreamReader.java:72)   at
>   java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:563)    at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.commands.stream.StreamToString.dumpStream(StreamToString.java:39)
>     at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.commands.stream.StreamToString.execute(StreamToString.java:33)
>     at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:87)
>     ... 8 more

My source code look like that:

```
import com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.commands.awaitCodeRedirect.LocalReceiver;
import com.cloudrail.si.services.Twitter;
public class testDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        com.cloudrail.si.CloudRail.setAppKey("5----------19");
        System.out.println("getAppKey: " + com.cloudrail.si.CloudRail.getAppKey());
        com.cloudrail.si.CloudRail.validateKey();
        Twitter service = new Twitter(
                new LocalReceiver(8042),
                "8KS-----1Hd",
                "gT---kzTu",
                "http://localhost:8042/auth"
        );
        service.login();
        System.out.println("end" );
    }
}
```

the identifiers come from this page:
[image]

How I can fixe it ?
Best regards,

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run the code? Does it crash immediately or does it open the website to perform the authentication and only crashes when you return back?

Comment: Hi there, thanks you for your reply. The code crash immediately, after to display my appkey of Cloudrail.

Comment: Did you setup the redirect URL on twitter APP website? (on the settings tab)